Integrating IBM Watson TTS in Unity VR project
For the beginning I just want to have a small scene with an input field where you can enter text which then gets outputted after you hit enter. I designed everything according to the test example from the Watson unity sdk https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk.
I built this scene:

And wrote this code:
using IBM.Watson.TextToSpeech.V1;
using IBM.Watson.TextToSpeech.V1.Model;
using IBM.Cloud.SDK.Utilities;
using IBM.Cloud.SDK.Authentication;
using IBM.Cloud.SDK.Authentication.Iam;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using IBM.Cloud.SDK;


namespace IBM.Watson.Examples
{
    public class ExampleTextToSpeechV1 : MonoBehaviour
    {
        #region PLEASE SET THESE VARIABLES IN THE INSPECTOR
        [Space(10)]
        [Tooltip("The IAM apikey.")]
        [SerializeField]
        private string iamApikey = "APIKEY";
        [Tooltip("The service URL (optional). This defaults to \"https://api.us-south.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com\"")]
        [SerializeField]
        private string serviceUrl = "https://api.eu-de.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/SERVICEINSTANCE";
        private TextToSpeechService service;
        private string allisionVoice = "en-US_AllisonV3Voice";
        private string synthesizeText = "Hello, my Name is Niclas.";
        private string placeholderText = "Please type text here and press enter.";
        private string waitingText = "Watson Text to Speech service is synthesizing the audio!";
        private string synthesizeMimeType = "audio/wav";
        public InputField textInput;
        private bool _textEntered = false;
        private AudioClip _recording = null;
        private byte[] audioStream = null;
        #endregion

        private void Start()
        {
            LogSystem.InstallDefaultReactors();
            Runnable.Run(CreateService());
        }

        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
            {
                Runnable.Run(ExampleSynthesize(textInput.text));
            }
        }

        private IEnumerator CreateService()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(iamApikey))
            {
                throw new IBMException("Please add IAM ApiKey to the Iam Apikey field in the inspector.");
            }

            IamAuthenticator authenticator = new IamAuthenticator(apikey: iamApikey);

            while (!authenticator.CanAuthenticate())
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            service = new TextToSpeechService(authenticator);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceUrl))
            {
                service.SetServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
            }
        }

        #region Synthesize Example
        private IEnumerator ExampleSynthesize(string text)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                text = synthesizeText;
                Log.Debug("ExampleTextToSpeechV1", "Using default text, please enter your own text in dialog box!");

            }
            byte[] synthesizeResponse = null;
            AudioClip clip = null;
            service.Synthesize(
                callback: (DetailedResponse<byte[]> response, IBMError error) =>
                {
                    synthesizeResponse = response.Result;
                    Log.Debug("ExampleTextToSpeechV1", "Synthesize done!");
                    clip = WaveFile.ParseWAV("myClip", synthesizeResponse);
                    PlayClip(clip);
                },
                text: text,
                voice: allisionVoice,
                accept: synthesizeMimeType
            );

            while (synthesizeResponse == null)
                yield return null;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(clip.length);
        }
        #endregion

        #region PlayClip
        private void PlayClip(AudioClip clip)
        {
            if (Application.isPlaying && clip != null)
            {
                GameObject audioObject = new GameObject("AudioObject");
                AudioSource source = audioObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
                source.spatialBlend = 0.0f;
                source.loop = false;
                source.clip = clip;
                source.Play();

                GameObject.Destroy(audioObject, clip.length);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}


I have no clue where my Problem is and how to resolve the errors seen in the screenshot above.
Those are the errors:

Saving has no effect. Your class 'UnityEditor.XR.Simulation.XREnvironmentViewManager' is missing the FilePathAttribute. Use this attribute to specify where to save your ScriptableSingleton.
Only call Save() and use this attribute if you want your state to survive between sessions of Unity.
UnityEditor.XR.Simulation.XREnvironmentViewManager:OnDisable () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@5.1.0/Editor/Simulation/XREnvironmentViewManager.cs:169)
Multiple scripted importers are targeting the extension 'glb' and have all been rejected: Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.Gltf.Serialization.Editor.GlbAssetImporter (assembly: D:\INDISUnity\INDIS\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Gltf.Importers.dll), GLTFast.Editor.GltfImporter (assembly: D:\INDISUnity\INDIS\Library\ScriptAssemblies\glTFast.Editor.dll)
UnityEditor.AssetImporters.ScriptedImporter:RegisterScriptedImporters ()
Multiple scripted importers are targeting the extension 'gltf' and have all been rejected: Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.Gltf.Serialization.Editor.GltfAssetImporter (assembly: D:\INDISUnity\INDIS\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Gltf.Importers.dll), GLTFast.Editor.GltfImporter (assembly: D:\INDISUnity\INDIS\Library\ScriptAssemblies\glTFast.Editor.dll)
UnityEditor.AssetImporters.ScriptedImporter:RegisterScriptedImporters ()
The referenced script (Unknown) on this Behaviour is missing!
No GetDeviceLayoutName() override detected in HP Reverb G2 Controller Profile. Binding path validator for this interaction profile is not as effective. To fix, add GetDeviceLayoutName and GetInteractionProfileType override in this profile.
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()


As you know, the golden rules on SO is to provide a MRE. This is not only so we can test and help you find the cause, but also, so you can see if you can reproduce it on an almost empty workspace. In some cases the errors appear from invalid third party additions (utilities, libraries, packages etc.) or because of incompatibility between them. Have you followed all the steps that IBM asks when installing it? Did you install anything in addition to what they asked or forgot anything? The error seems to point to an incompatibility.

My suggestion is to stop and make a new empty project and just try to see where the error appears step by step. For example, first just connect to Watson and do a "hello world with him". In a separate empty project, import your VR dependencies and make a basic "hello world" VR test. Next, combine them, try to track your issue. Also, if you do need to download additional packages, don't install all of them at once and then wait to see if you have an error, but rather check your project after each third party installation.

Also, please edit your question, copy-paste the full and untruncated errors from the Console and inline them in your post. You can keep the picture since it also presents the scene, but the errors should be present in the question itself.

@TheNomad Yes I did all the steps IBM asked me to do. We have installed quite a few other packages because we are building a vr medical training application. But yeah testing in an empty project seems to be a good option. Now everything should be in the question, right?

In general, yeah, eliminate each package, start with the minimum from IBM (as I said, same as with MREs for coding) then after each addition, best is to shutdown and restart the editor and test if it works (just in case some take a while to "refresh"). As I said, it seems to be a conflict so your options are either to drop some features or to find an alternative third party (utility, lib or package). Otherwise, it's hard for me (I don't want to speak for others) to tell you how to solve it. Elimination is your friend (in a "non-assassin" and "non-secret gov agency" way, of course).
